# Poor results with Keras inbuilt VGG16 model on cats vs. dogs dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, kaggle

I am trying to apply the inbuilt VGG16 Keras model to the [Kaggle Cats vs Dogs](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition) dataset.

However, I get 52% accuracy which is barely better than complete hazard.

Any idea why this would be the case? [Download notebook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8gbliyt76bsurr/vgg_own.ipynb?dl=0)

Vlad

Comment: Post your code here please , we can't download notebook!

Comment: Hi, the notebook is public so you should be able to download.

Comment: I know that we can download it , but probably we don't have time , so it's better for you and your question to post your code here , people don't like link reference codes here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was using a very high learning rate (0.01).

I have since amended the learning rate to `lr=0.0001` and the accuracy after one epoch is closer to 95%, which is the expected result.